# Add logo in navigation bar before menu items in twenty thirteen?

Tags: theme-twenty-thirteen

I am customizing the twenty thirteen theme and want to add a logo image in the navigation bar before menu items like [this link.](http://orangeleafyogurt.com/)

I have tried different approaches but didn't work.

Would appreciate any suggestions in this regard.

Comment: show your code...wat u tried so far.

Comment: I tried `.nav-menu ul:before` to display image before ul displaying menu items but it was creating disturbance

Comment: show your code buddy.

Comment: also tried to echo the image in different places within header.php in    `<div id="navbar" class="navbar">`

Comment: Suggest you to do the changes in a child theme. Otherwise the changes will wipe out on the next update on TwentyThirteen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on a Twenty Thirteen & Twenty Twelve child theme.

[image]

Try this from your child themes functions.php file.

You can add the image using various methods.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpsites_add_logo_nav_menu', 10, 2 );

function wpsites_add_logo_nav_menu( $menu, stdClass $args ){

if ( 'primary' != $args->theme_location )
    return $menu;


$menu .= '<nav class="nav-image"><img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/header.png" /></nav>';

return $menu;

}
```

Sample CSS for your child themes style.css file:

```
.nav-logo {
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

You'd also want some Media Queries which will vary per theme.

Here's the result on Twenty Twelve:

[image]

Comment: Thanks brad. Done already but it might help some one else in the community.

Comment: Did you forget something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that:

```
.nav-logo {
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

should read:

```
.nav-image {
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

That's what worked for me.